# Pausing loop until child process send message in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a process which passes messages into a child process for processing in the middle of a loop and then should continue depending the response from the child.

I however don't know how to pause the loop to allow the child process to complete and proceed once we get a message.

Here is how the function looks like

```
function runTests()
{
  allTests = getTests()
  allTests.forEach(test => {
    console.log(chalk.blue.bold.underline('Running: '+ test.title))
    for(i = 0;i < test.questions.length;i++)
    {
      //Fork child process. 
      const poll = fork('poll.js',['999999', new Date()])
      poll.send(test.questions[i])
      poll.on('message', msg => {

     if(assert("msg.includes('error')",msg))
     {
      console.log(chalk.blue.bold.underline('Child response: '+ msg))
     }
  });
 }
}) 
}
```

Comment: Better give a try to (ES6) Generators. Hope that will resolve your problem :)


Take a look of official docs or here :
https://medium.com/dailyjs/a-simple-guide-to-understanding-javascript-es6-generators-d1c350551950

Comment: this article is also good for generators : https://vegibit.com/es6-generators/